# How to delete user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-users

This may sounds a stupid question but I have difficulty deleting users in django using this view:

```
@staff_member_required 
def del_user(request, username):    
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username = username)
        u.delete()
        messages.sucess(request, "The user is deleted")
    except:
      messages.error(request, "The user not found")    
    return render(request, 'front.html')
```

in urls.py I have

```
url(r'^del_user/(?P<username>[\w|\W.-]+)/$', 'profile.views.del_user'),
```

Instead the user being deleted I get `The user not found`.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Well you are goind into the except block, it is not a good idea use a generic except. You could try printing the error you're getting.

Comment: Remove the try and except to look for any errors.

Comment: There's probably too little information here for us to help you, but one thing you might try is opening up a python console in your environment and manually run each step. I find that tends to illuminate a lot of issues. (just remember to do "from django import setup" and then "setup()" first if using Django 1.7+

Comment: Use `try: yourcode... expect DoesNotExist: dosomething...` instead.

Answer (score 17):

You should change your code to:

```
@staff_member_required 
def del_user(request, username):    
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username = username)
        u.delete()
        messages.success(request, "The user is deleted")            

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "User doesnot exist")    
        return render(request, 'front.html')

    except Exception as e: 
        return render(request, 'front.html',{'err':e.message})

    return render(request, 'front.html')
```

and display the `err` in your template to see further error messages

Comment: I want a button for this, so when I click the button beside the User in a ListView of users, then it takes that users pk, so I can filter it.

Answer (score -5):

```
@login_required
def del_user(request):
    user = request.user
    user.delete()
    redirect("login")
```

Comment: OP didn't want to delete the user enacting the request.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35012475)