# Remove user in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to remove user.

I know that probably I can use some library like allauth but I want to do this on my view.
I didn't find any tutorial for that so I am trying to do this learn-by-mistakes way.

Ok. so in urls I have:

```
urlpatterns = [

    ('^remove$', views.remove_user, name="remove"),
]
```

forms:

```
class RemoveUser(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)
```

views:

```
@login_required(login_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
def remove_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RemoveUser(request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        if form.is_valid():
            rem = User.objects.get(username=username)
            rem.delete()
            return redirect('main')
    else:
        form = RemoveUser()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'remove_user.html', context)
```

I can access website and type text in textfield. When I type random username I get error "user does not exist" so everything ok, but when I type correct username I get message: "A user with that username already exists" and this user is not removed.

Please, can you help me with that?

Comment: Note that it's more usual to make a user inactive than to delete him, so that data connected to the user isn't deleted, other people can't register a new user that uses the old username, etc. If a user has active=False, he can't login anymore.

Comment: @utkbansal thanks, edited

Comment: @RemcoGerlich that seems like a nice idea. can you chow how to do this?

Comment: @Maciejjy your form validation fails in case of a correct username.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33716586/5751147 read here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your form to a normal form-

```
class RemoveUser(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
```

The view will be as follows -

```
@login_required(login_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
def remove_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RemoveUser(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            rem = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
            if rem is not None:
                rem.delete()
                return redirect('main')
            else:
               ## Send some error messgae
    else:
        form = RemoveUser()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'remove_user.html', context)
```

EDIT-- Another way to approach the same problem is to deactivate the user

```
    if form.is_valid():
        rem = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
        if rem is not None:
            rem.is_active = False
            rem.save()
```

Comment: Ok that work now. I had to change form from ModelForm to Form just like you said. Thanks.